# Задачка по регулярном выражении

Tags: php

Подскажите как в регулярном выражении задать

> 23.10.2023 время 18:00 <a href=../Y222000.html?op=001> текст

Y222000 и 001 не известны

`preg_replace('<a href=../ОСТАВИТЬ.html?op=001>', '', $array);`

В результате получить 23.10.2023 время 18:00 Y222000 текст

Хотел заменять найденые восхождения но проблема в том что подменять .html?op=001> не получиться так как числа 001 разные.

```
$result= str_replace("<a href=../", "", $array);
```

Comment: Изменил на более точное описание! Изначально думал подменять восхеждения str_replace в строчках, но в каждой строке (.html?op=001>) цифры имеют разное значение. А с регуляркой не знаю как правильно задать с чего начать менять и до куда а что оставить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<?php 
$array = ["23.10.2023 время 18:50 <a href=../Y222004.html?op=009> текст1","27.10.2023 время 15:00 <a href=../Y222000.html?op=888> текст2","13.10.2023 время 18:10 <a href=../Y222800.html?op=007> текст3","23.11.2023 время 14:00 <a href=../Y222001.html?op=004> текст4"];
$res = preg_replace('/<[^\/]+\/|\.html[^>]+>/', "", $array);
var_dump($res);
?>
```

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(47) "23.10.2023 время 18:50 Y222004 текст1"
  [1]=>
  string(47) "27.10.2023 время 15:00 Y222000 текст2"
  [2]=>
  string(47) "13.10.2023 время 18:10 Y222800 текст3"
  [3]=>
  string(47) "23.11.2023 время 14:00 Y222001 текст4"
}
```

Comment: Извеняюсь я наверное не совсем корректно указал $array это массив в котором я пытаюсь найти и изменить все восхождения <a href=../Y222000.html?op=001>не обрезая другие данные все что до и после.

Comment: Если быть точным то строка имеет занчения (23.10.2023 время 18:00 <a href=../Y222000.html?op=001> текст ) я пытаюсь получить (23.10.2023 время 18:00 Y222000 текст). И заменить в массиве все восхождения <a href=../ОСТАВИТЬ.html?op=???>

Comment: Я думал вот $array= str_replace("<a href=../", "", $array); Но проблема в том что изменить .html?op=001> я не могу так как значения 001 есть другие.

Comment: Алексей Р. Спасибо огромное за ваше время и труд но к сажелению єто не то.  Ваш способоб выводит Y222000 удаляя все что было до и после! Вопрос как удалить только <a href=../.html?op=001> больше ничего не изменяя (текст <a href=../Y222000.html?op=001> текст), результат (текст Y222000 текст ). Зная что текст какой нужно удалить начинаеться  <a заканчивая ../  и также со второй частью начиная .html заканчивая >.  Или начиная от <a +8 символов удалить итд.. Я себе это так представлял но незнаю так ли это.

Comment: @Serg_rv вроде понял, что нужно. Переделал.

Comment: Спасибо большое!